# How pass parameters between controller and view Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

My parameter is an array:

Controller:

```
$data=......;
$this->load->view('a/p/l',$data);
```

The data vector has like parameter:

```
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
 'email' => string '' (length=21)
      ...
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
 'email' => string '' (length=21)
     ...
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'email' => string '' (length=21)
```

Anyone can show mem some View that I can read the elements in to the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example

Here is my controller named welcome.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

        $data['default'] = array(
            array(
                'email' => 'sample@gmail.com',
                'username' => 'username1'
            ),

            array(
                'email' => 'sample@yahoo.com',
                'username' => 'username2'
            ),

            array(
                'email' => 'sample@hot.com',
                'username' => 'username3'
            )
        );

        $data['title'] = 'Sample';

        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
    }

}
```

In order to call the pass $data array in the views, we make sure that we have a reference key for the array like

> $data['default'] = array
>
> $data['title'] = 'Sample';

In order for me to access those data in my view
here is a sample view named

welcome_message.php

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <?php
                foreach ($default as $key => $value) {
            ?>
            <h1><?php echo $value['email'];?></h1>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
            
            <h6><?php echo $title;?></h6>
            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

To be able to access those data pass, I used the reference key of the pass array

> default and title

and from there I can do the processing already

hope It could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the data array's `index` must be an associative index it must be letters first. CI convert the array as variable in view.

Example:

```
$data=array('value1'=>12,'value2'=>23)
$this->load->view('a/p/l',$data);
```

you can now access the values of the passed array by treating the indexes as new variable.

in your **view** you can get the value of `value1 index` like this

```
echo $value1;
```

I think it won't work if you use a number as index, it is a basic php rules in variables.